# Assigning to full property upon construction

Tags: c#, properties

If I have an auto property in C#, I can assign a value to it, upon instatiation of the class, like this:

```
public DateTime DesiredBookingDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

However, if I have a full property, with a backing field, I cannot do the same:

```
// This doesn't work
private DateTime _desiredBookingDate;
public DesiredBookDate 
{
    get => _desiredBookingDate;
    set => SetProperty(ref _desiredBookingDate, value);
} = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Is there any way I can do something like this, without using the constructor (and in an easy-to-read way)?

**Update:**

The reason I have been hessitant to just assign the value to the backing field, is because I cannot figure out if there are any scenarios where this could affect the functionality of `INotifyPropertyChange`. But if they compile to the same, that would be fine.

Comment: `private DateTime _desiredBookingDate = DateTime.Now.Date;`.

Comment: Initialize the backing property?

Comment: Are there any scenarios where this could affect the `INotifyPropertyChanged` functionality?

Comment: @Noceo - does it matter in your case? It's setting the property to an initial value, not changing it. Triggering any `INotifyPropertyChanged` would seem a little counterintuitive to me. If you need to do something when it's initialized, using the constructor would seem more appropriate.

Comment: Either initialize the field, or call the setter in the constructor.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb probably not. But I have always had a practice of using the public properties, to always trigger `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's why I wasn't completely sure if it was the right way to go, to set the private property. But it appears to be the way to go, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the backing field to your value.

```
private DateTime _desiredBookingDate = DateTime.Now.Date;  
public DesiredBookDate 
{
    get => _desiredBookingDate;
    set => SetProperty(ref _desiredBookingDate, value);
}
```

If you need to do any `INotifyPropertyChanged` functionality, you can call the setter from the constructor.

Just FYI, I threw your first example of the auto property into a simple app and used IL Spy, and it spit the following out:

```
internal class Program
{
    public DateTime DesiredBookingDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
    }

    public Program()
    {
        this.<DesiredBookingDate>k__BackingField = DateTime.Now.Date;
        base..ctor();
    }
}
```